# $\mathbb{E}[e^{-\mu B_T}\max_{t\in[0,T]} B_t]\sim e^{\mu^2 T/2}/2\mu$ as $T\to\infty$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

This is an exercise from Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications by Michael Steele (Exercise 13.1).
The goal is to use Girsanov's theorem to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\mu B_T}\max_{t\in[0,T]} B_t\right]\sim e^{\mu^2 T/2}/2\mu\quad\text{and}\quad \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\mu B_T}\max_{t\in[0,T]} B_t\right]\sim \mu Te^{\mu^2 T/2},
$$
as $T\to\infty$, where $\mu>0$.

Here's my attempt for the first relation.
Denoting by $\mathbb{P}$ the probability measure of the standard Brownian motion $\{B_t\}$, we define $W_t=B_t-\mu t$ and
$$
d\mathbb{Q} = \exp\left(-\mu B_T-\frac{1}{2}\mu^2 T\right)\,d\mathbb{P}.
$$
Then, $\{W_t\}$ is a Brownian motion with respect to $d\mathbb{Q}$, by Girsanov's theorem, and we can write
$$
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[e^{-\mu B_T}\max_{t\in[0,T]} B_t\right] = e^{\frac{1}{2}\mu^2T}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[\max_{t\in[0,T]} (W_t+\mu t)\right].
$$
This is where I'm stuck; I don't know how to deduce the asymptotic relation from the right hand side. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need to use Girsanov's theorem? You can use the joint distribution of $(B_T, 
\max_{t\in[0,T]}B_t)$

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think your suggestion is much simpler to reach the desired conclusion. However, using Girsanov's theorem is a part of this problem, since this is an exercise in a chapter on Girsanov's theorem.